# Join query by date and primary

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the followings tables on my database

[image: database tables]

There are several *project statuses* (waiting, working, finished, paid) and a project have to pass through all the status from waiting to paid.

In order to keep complete track of the project, each status are kept, so we know when a project changed its status.

I would like to create a *search filter* with the **current status** (the one with the more recent "created_at").

I tried few queries in order to get the correct result, but I'm stuck with this one.

The not-working query I have is

```
select p.* from projects p
left join projects_status_projects psp on psp.project_id = p.id
where p.id in (select project_id from projects_status_projects 
      where project_status_id = XX group by project_id order by created_at desc)
```

Ofc, this query does not work and return me each projects with a record for project_status_id XX without taking in account the order.

Any hint would be very appreciated !

Thanks,
Benjamin

Comment: This does not need to have a separate join table (projects_status_projects) since each project status will only belong to one project (if i've read the question correctly). The project_statuses table should simply have a project_id column. This would make your queries easier to manage.

Comment: @Slicedpan, maybe my question was not correctly redacted, but the project_statuses table contains "status labels" such as "paid, waiting and so on" (this allows us to add new status and avoid constants).

So the join table is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.* from projects p
left join projects_status_projects psp on (psp.project_id = p.id)
where created_at = (select max(created_at) 
                    from projects_status_projects where
                    project_id = p.id)
```

sqlfiddle with some example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/725fcc/7/0

Comment: For the complete query, I had to add `and project_status_id = XX`

Thanks for your good answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the current status of the project

Try this::

```
Select DITINCT(p.id),p.* 
from projects p
left join projects_status_projects psp on psp.project_id = p.id
where project_status_id = XX 
order by created_at desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of solving it:

```
select p.* from projects p
left join projects_status_projects psp on psp.project_id = p.id
where p.id in (select project_id from projects_status_projects 
      where project_status_id = XX and created_at = min(created_at) group by project_id)
```

Comment: First query wont give the result

Comment: You are right, the first one was gibberish, so I removed it and kept only the second one.

Comment: Removed the -1 now...
:-)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 select p.* from projects p
    left join projects_status_projects psp on psp.project_id = p.id
    where psp.id = (select max(id) from projects_status_projects 
          where projects_status_projects.project_id =p.id ) and psp.project_status_id = XX
```

or

```
select p.* from projects p,projects_status_projects psp
    where psp.project_id = p.id and psp.id = (select max(id) from projects_status_projects 
          where projects_status_projects.project_id =p.id ) and psp.project_status_id = XX
```