# Ruby complex query elegant solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

in my rails 4 project, I have the following tables
[image]

In this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248761/join-query-by-date-and-primary), I searched for a SQL query to fetch the *projects* with the actual *project status id* = XX. By actual, I mean the one with the max(created_at).

I got an answer for my query which is

```
select p.* from projects p
     left join projects_status_projects psp on (psp.project_id = p.id)
     where created_at = (select max(created_at) from projects_status_projects 
           where project_id = p.id)    
     and project_status_id = XX
```

My models are defined

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :projects_status_projects
   has_many :projects_statuses, :through => :projects_status_projects
end

class ProjectStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :projects_status_projects
   has_many :projects, :through => :projects_status_projects
end

class ProjectsStatusType < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :project
   belongs_to :project_status
end
```

In my *Project* model, I have the following method

```
def self.with_status(status)
   joins(:projects_status_projects)
       .where('projects_status_projects.created_at = (select max(created_at) from 
                    projects_status_projects where project_id = p.id)')
       .where('projects_status_projects.project_status_id = ?', status)
end
```

While the query is correct, the received results are well filtered, I find this solution terrible and not elegant at all.

Is there any way to get the same result with scopes ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of

```
scope :with_status, -> (status) { 
   ProjectsStatusType.where(:project_status_id, status).order(:created_at).last.project 
}
```

EDIT based on comments :

As sockmonk said, scopes should be chainable. Here is a cleaner way to do it, which also fix the problem if no project is found.

```
# ProjectStatusType model
scope :with_ordered_status, -> (status) { 
   where(:project_status_id, status).order(:created_at)
}

# Project model
def self.find_by_status(status)
  project_statuses = ProjectsStatusType.with_ordered_status(status)
  project_statuses.any? ? project_statuses.last.project : nil
end
```

Comment: Your method is really elegant, the main problem is the 
`undefined method 'project' for nil:NilClass` if the request return no result (for this status)

Answer (score 0):

how about?

```
scope :with_status, ->(status = "default_status") {
    joins(:projects_status_projects).
    where('projects_status_projects.project_status_id = ?', status).
    order("projects_status_projects.created_at DESC").first
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :with_status, ->(status = "default_status") {
  joins(:projects_status_projects)
  .where('projects_status_projects.project_status_id = ?', status)
  .order("projects_status_projects.created_at DESC")    
}
```

When you call it, you'll want to tack a '.first' to the end of it; can't include the .first in the scope itself, as that would make it unchainable.

Comment: Telepathy or copy&paste?

Comment: note the explanation. Scopes need to return a Relation so that they can be chained, so it won't work if .first is in the scope; .first returns either a single activerecord object or nil if none are found

Comment: maybe the fact I'm a ruby/rails newbie is the cause of this. But I don't know if this scope will work to return all projects with this status ?  

I mean, if I call something like `@projects = Project.with_status(XX).first`, I will only receive the first project with status XX ?

Comment: Calling Project.with_status(XX) will return all projects with that status; calling Project.with_status(XX).first will return just the project with the most recent created_at date with that status.